# Returning objects back to a form

Tags: c#

I'm a bit new to C# and I'm having a bit of trouble with this code.  I apologize if the answer is a trivial thing that I'm missing.

In brief, I'm making something similar to an rpg.  The main form has a "start" button.  When that button is pressed, some information is read from a text file and that information is used to set up the characters.  I have all of the logic I need working in the setup class, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to return the final setup object array back to the form.  The form will need the information in those objects back to setup some picture boxes and labels.

**Here is the code from the "start" button click event:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // setup players
            Player[] player = new Player[5];
            SetupPlayers setupPlayers = new SetupPlayers();
            setupPlayers.getPlayerData();
        }
```

**and from the Player classes:**

```
public class Player
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string mood { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        public bool participate { get; set; }

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets player info from setup.txt file, sets up number of players, ID of each player, and calculates mood
    /// </summary>
    public class SetupPlayers
    {
        public SetupPlayers()
        {

        }


        public void getPlayerData()
        {
            int totalPossiblePlayers = 5;
            int numberOfPlayers = 0;
            String[] playerName = new string[12];
            String[] attr1 = new string[12]; String[] attr2 = new string[12]; String[] attr3 = new string[12]; String[] attr4 = new string[12]; String[] attr5 = new string[12]; String[] attr6 = new string[12]; String[] attr7 = new string[12]; String[] attr8 = new string[12];
            String[] color = new string[12]; String[] iconP = new string[12];


            StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("setup.txt");

            for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
            {
                if (SR.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    var splitLine = SR.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    playerName[counter] = splitLine[0];
                    attr1[counter] = splitLine[1]; attr2[counter] = splitLine[2]; attr3[counter] = splitLine[3]; attr4[counter] = splitLine[4]; attr5[counter] = splitLine[5]; attr6[counter] = splitLine[6]; attr7[counter] = splitLine[7]; attr8[counter] = splitLine[8];
                    color[counter] = splitLine[9]; iconP[counter] = splitLine[10];
                }
            }           
            SR.Close();

            Player[] player = new Player[totalPossiblePlayers];
            for (int i = 0; i < totalPossiblePlayers; i++)
            {
                player[i] = new Player();
                player[i].name = playerName[i];
                player[i].icon = iconP[i];
                player[i].color = color[i];
                player[i].mood = setPlayerMood(i, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5, attr6, attr7, attr8);
                player[i].participate = doesPlayerJoin();
                

            }
           }     
//setPlayerMood and doesPlayerJoin code below removed, they are working great

    }
```

So I need all this player[] object array to be accessible to the form.

Thanks for reading!

Ken

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values  Here's the docs on how values are returned from method calls.

Comment: Change return type from void to Player[] : public void getPlayerData()

Comment: I tried that, but the player[] was still not accessible to the form.  Do I need to declare something on the form?  Or for example, how do I retrieve player[0].name then?

Comment: You're creating the player array in the button's click event, so it's only available to code in that procedure. You need to create the array in the form's declarations section so it will be available to all code on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return players and assign it in button click event.

I have made sme modifications to setup players like having using statement for streamreader & simplified streamReader.

```cs
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // setup players
            SetupPlayers setupPlayers = new SetupPlayers();
            Player[] players = setupPlayers.getPlayerData();
        }

public Player[] getPlayerData()
    {
      var totalPossiblePlayers = 5;
      var numberOfPlayers = 0;
      var playerName = new string[12];
      var attr1 = new string[12];
      var attr2 = new string[12];
      var attr3 = new string[12];
      var attr4 = new string[12];
      var attr5 = new string[12];
      var attr6 = new string[12];
      var attr7 = new string[12];
      var attr8 = new string[12];
      var color = new string[12];
      var iconP = new string[12];


      using var sr = System.IO.File.OpenText("setup.txt");

      for (var counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
      {
        if (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
          var splitLine = sr.ReadLine()?.Split(',');
          if (splitLine != null)
          {
            playerName[counter] = splitLine[0];
            attr1[counter] = splitLine[1];
            attr2[counter] = splitLine[2];
            attr3[counter] = splitLine[3];
            attr4[counter] = splitLine[4];
            attr5[counter] = splitLine[5];
            attr6[counter] = splitLine[6];
            attr7[counter] = splitLine[7];
            attr8[counter] = splitLine[8];
            color[counter] = splitLine[9];
            iconP[counter] = splitLine[10];
          }
        }
      }

      Player[] player = new Player[totalPossiblePlayers];
      for (var i = 0; i < totalPossiblePlayers; i++)
      {
        player[i] = new Player();
        player[i].name = playerName[i];
        player[i].icon = iconP[i];
        player[i].color = color[i];
        player[i].mood = setPlayerMood(i, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5, attr6, attr7, attr8);
        player[i].participate = doesPlayerJoin();
      }

      return player;
    }
```

Comment: This is what I was missing  "Player[] players = setupPlayers.getPlayerData();"  (after I added the return type).  THANK YOU SO MUCH, works like a charm now.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help!